# How can I replace text in a Siebel data mapping?

Tags: siebel, eai, data-mapping

I have an outgoing web service to send data from Siebel 7.8 to an external system. In order for the integration to work, before I send the data, I must change one of the field values, replacing every occurence of `"old"` with `"new"`. **How can I do this with EAI data mappings?**

---

In an ideal world I would just use an integration source expression like `Replace([Description], "old", "new")`. However Siebel is far from ideal, and doesn't have a replace function (or if it does, it's not documented). I can use [all the Siebel query language functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/PersAdm/PersAdmfunctions.html) which [don't need an execution context](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/EAI4/EAI4_DATAMapUSDecDTE21.html). I can also use the [functions available for calculated fields](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/ToolsDevRef/operators_conditions11.html#wp138950) (*sane people* could expect both lists to be the same, but Siebel documentation is also far from ideal).

My first attempt was to use the `InvokeServiceMethod` function and replace the text myself in eScript. So, this is my field map source expression:

```
InvokeServiceMethod('MyBS', 'MyReplace', 'In="' + [Description] + '"', 'Out')
```

After [some configuration steps](http://www.error-codes.info/2010/12/sbl-dat-00610-access-denied-to-invoke.html) it works fine... except if my description field contains the `"` character: `Error parsing expression 'In="This is a "test" with quotes"' for field '3' (SBL-DAT-00481)`

I know why this happens. My double quotes are breaking the expression and I have to escape them by doubling the character, as in `This is a ""test"" with quotes`. However, how can I replace each `"` with `""` in order to call my business service... if I don't have a replace function? :)

Oracle's support web has only [one result for the SBL-DAT-00481 error](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=949078.1), which as a workaround, suggests to place the whole parameter inside double quotes (which I already had). There's [a linked document](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=949078.1&id=521262.1) in which they acknowledge that the workaround is valid for a few characters such as commas or single quotes, but due to a bug in Siebel 7.7-7.8 (not present in 8.0+), it doesn't work with double quotes. They suggest to pass instead the row id as argument to the business service, and then retrieve the data directly from the BC.

Before I do that and end up with a performance-affecting workaround (pass only the ID) for the workaround (use double quotes) for the workaround (use InvokeServiceMethod) for not having a replace function... Am I going crazy here? Isn't there a *simple* way to do a simple text replacement in a Siebel data mapping?

Answer (score 0):

first thing (quite possibly - far from optimal one) which is coming to my mind - is to create at source BC calculated field, aka (NEW_VALUE), which becomes "NEW" for every record, where origin field has a value "OLD". and simply use this field in integration map.

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting... unless it's an `IIF` calculated expression? That wouldn't work, my field doesn't have "new" as a value, it contains it. It may be "new hope", or "the newest news in newcastle", or whatever, and I need to change them into "old hope", "the oldest olds in oldcastle", etc.

Comment: I just noticed that I said it backwards in my previous comment. "old hope" would become "new hope" and not the other way around :). Anyway it doesn't matter, it was just a simplified example of what I actually need...